# How to reference a value in a dictionary if the value is a list of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop, twitter

I'm collecting data from Twitter, and each tweet is in the form of a dictionary.

My full dataset is a list of thousands of tweets (a list of dictionaries).

**I want to reference the hashtags within each tweet but I need help figuring out how to do this.**

Here's an example of a list of two partial tweets with relevant data:

```
twitter_tweets =  
[{'created_at': 'Wed Oct 18 22:20:30 +0000 2017', 'id': 920776631102214144, 'entities': {'hashtags': ['#dataanalyst#', '#politics']} 'user': {'id': 119116331, 'statuses_count': 32796, 'verified': False, 'lang': 'en-'}, 'retweet_count': 0, 'favorite_count': 0}
{'created_at': 'Wed Oct 17 12:20:36 +0000 2017', 'id': 920776631106514144, 'entities': {'hashtags': ['#california', '#nationalparks']}  'user': {'id': 119159331, 'statuses_count': 32796, 'verified': False, 'lang': 'en-gb'}, 'retweet_count': 1, 'favorite_count': 2}]
```

Notice that the "entities" key has as its value a second dictionary. In that second dictionary, "hashtags" is the key and the value is a list of hashtags.

Here is the code I have attempting to collect a list of all of these hashtags to create a frequency series:

```
def make_tweets_series(input_list, first_key, second_key):
    final_keys_list = []
    for line in input_list:
        tweets_by_key = line[first_key][second_key]
        final_keys_list.append(tweets_by_key)
        series_key_values = pd.Series(final_keys_list).value_counts()

    return series_key_values


hashtag_distribution_series = make_tweets_series(twitter_tweets, 'entities', 'hashtags')
```

This code would work, I think, if the "hashtags" value was a string, but it doesn't work because "hashtags"  is a list of strings.

How can I reference each of the hashtags in these lists and put them into a Series?

My full error message, with the traceback, is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-60-7623feb35c84>", line 13, in <module>
    hashtag_distribution_series = make_tweets_series(twitter_tweets, 'entities', 'hashtags')

  File "<ipython-input-60-7623feb35c84>", line 6, in make_tweets_series
    series_key_values = pd.Series(final_keys_list).value_counts()

  File "/home/tommy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 938, in value_counts
    normalize=normalize, bins=bins, dropna=dropna)

  File "/home/tommy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 640, in value_counts
    keys, counts = _value_counts_arraylike(values, dropna)

  File "/home/tommy/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 685, in _value_counts_arraylike
    keys, counts = f(values, dropna)

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_func_helper.pxi", line 356, in pandas._libs.hashtable.value_count_object (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:29440)

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_func_helper.pxi", line 367, in pandas._libs.hashtable.value_count_object (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:29189)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: whenever you post an error, please post the entire trace back

Comment: Do you realize that hashtags need to be a string when used as a key? which isn't the case in your input. Not sure if its typo or an error.

Comment: @utengr Yes, that was a typo. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

## `list` is unhashable

Literally what it means; you cannot hash a `list` object. `dict`s use the hash value of objects to find key -> value; it's faster that way.

Use `tuple` instead, so where the list of strings is being returned, just call `tuple(...)`. Tuples are immutable ordered collections that behave similarly to lists except are immutable and hashable.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to use tuple(). Where in my code would it go?

Comment: @ThomasErnste `series_key_values = pd.Series(tuple(final_keys_list)).value_counts()`

Comment: I'm not sure if I changed the code the way you intended.  I tried substituting your line "series_key_values = pd.Series(tuple(final_keys_list)).value_counts()" in my code instead of my line "series_key_values = pd.Series(final_keys_list).value_counts()"    I get the same error message -- " TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: @ThomasErnste Hm. Try `final_keys_list.append(tuple(tweets_by_key))` Also, the `series_key_values = ...` should go after the loop ends.